# regex selecting everything in a line but skip third word

Tags: regex

How do I select everything from the current line except the third word? 
The third word will be different (photo,video,music etc)
The line will sometimes end with a number wrapped with () but not always

```
My download photo file(4)
My download photo file(2)
My download video file
```

I'm not using this along with any other language. I'm using a file renamer program that has the ability to select with regex

In the end I will use the Windows file renamer program to rename files to end with creation date and time photo_2014-02-16_1630.jpg

Comment: What a lousy file renamer you have?  It can _accept_ a regex, but can't _suggest_ one?

Comment: If you are not using the regex within "any other language", you are using it within a software (your renamer program) that imposes certain restrictions and assumptions on the regex that can be used - presumeably those of the library or language used to create that renamer application. You will need to tell us about that then so we can suggest anything. Also, you forgot to show how far you got when you tried on your own, and in which cases the regex you developed yourself fails.

Comment: All your examples start with "My download" and end with "file" or "file(n)". Are all your files named like this? What do you want to rename them to? If you were more specific, we may be able to help.

Comment: What "third word" is it when the name is `My_download_photo(10)_file(4)
` ?

Comment: In the end I will use the Windows file renamer program to rename files to end with creation date and time photo_2014-02-16_1630.jpg

Comment: Yes file names will always follow the same pattern that was posted in the question. Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP should have a minimal understanding of the problem by showing what has been attempted and the problems encountered in the attempt(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can this regex for matching:

```
^((?:\S+\s+){2})\S+\s*(.*)$
```

And use back-reference #1 and #2 for replacement:

```
\1\2
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/nC5tM3

Comment: A code snippet for copy and pasting without any explanation may solve the current, immenent issue of the OP, but does nothing to help them *understand how* the problem was solved, and how similar problems can be solved in the future. As such, this response is not very useful for future visitors either, who may have similar, but most probably not exactly the same problem.

Comment: Had I not included a working demo link (which explains every detail of the regex used) it would have been a fair comment. I can sure copy/paste same explanation in my answer also.